# postgresql 11 select queries time go to increase

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-11

We have setup postgres 11 database for a web application. My OS is ubnutu 18 and serer cores are 12 with 32 GB memory. As our data is going to increase, select query time is also increasing. Current we have 40 GB data. I think it is not too much. Why some select query is taking too much time.

```
select t_id, user_id from "MyData" where t_time<='2020-06-09 09:00:00' order by t_time desc  limit 10;
```

I am using database with default configuration. How to optimize it for time query improvement.

Comment: How much time does it take ? Do you have indexes on the t_time column ?

Comment: 30 to 50 seconds

Comment: I have not created any indexes on t_time column. Would it be better ?

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the [execution plan](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/using-explain.html) generated using **`explain (analyze, buffers, format text)`** (_not_ just a "simple" explain) as  [formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) and make sure you prevent the indention of the plan. Paste the text, then put `\`\`\`` on the line before the plan and on a line after the plan. Please also include complete `create index` statements for all indexes as well.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: you should really avoid those dreaded quoted identifiers. They are much more trouble than they are worth it. https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_upper_case_table_or_column_names